# A formula is a tautology iff its negation is a contradiction

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Here's the exact problem;

Let $\alpha$ be a formula in the language of propositional logic $L_p$. $\alpha$ is a tautology iff $(\lnot \alpha)$ is a contradiction.

---

Proof Attempt:

Suppose that $\alpha$ is a tautology. So, for every truth assignment $v$, $v(\alpha) = T$. That implies that for every truth assignment, $v((\lnot \alpha)) = F$. That is, there is no truth assignment $v$ which satisfies $(\lnot \alpha)$. Hence, $(\lnot \alpha)$ is a contradiction.

Suppose that $\lnot \alpha$ is a contradiction. Now, suppose that $\alpha$ is not a tautology. Then, there is a truth assignment $v$ that fails to satisfy $\alpha$. That is, $v(\alpha) = F$. But that means that $v((\lnot \alpha)) = T$. This means that $v$ satisfies $(\lnot \alpha)$ and that is impossible. Hence, $\alpha$ is a tautology. $\Box$

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: It works, but you can shorten it using only the first part: every step in the argument is an iff: $\alpha$ is a taut iff every truth assign...

Comment: Your write-up is clear and convincing.  Note that the key here is how *tautology* and *contradiction* are defined relative to the propositional logic.

Comment: Yes, I was rather surprised looking at the definition of these things in propositional logic. They seem to be modelling how we think tautologies and contradictions should behave in our metalogic (I guess that's the right word? Call me out on it if it isn't), except that they're defined only in terms of the language of propositional logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much for the feedback, I'll shorten it using that approach :D

Comment: "I was rather surprised looking at the definition of these things in propositional logic." Why ? A [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Definition_and_examples) in propositional logic is defined as "a formula that is always true, regardless of which valuation is used for the propositional variables."

Comment: It is the propositional version of *valid* formula, e.g. a formula that is true in every interpretation.

Comment: Well, I am more used to the form where it's like "A tautology is a statement that is always true.". I was expecting it to be defined like that in my text. However, it was defined more like "A formula is a tautology iff it is satisfied by every truth assignment." That really just means that for every truth assignment $v$, $v(\alpha) = T$, where $\alpha$ is the formula in question. I was just surprised because of the difference in definition.

Comment: I do admit that I am still quite curious about how set theory intermixes with all of this. Professor Scott gave me some pretty good intuition about this but I am kind of wondering how we would build all of this up such that I can freely use the word "set" in propositional logic without any reservations (since we're kind of freely using it when describing collections of symbols and formulas). But I guess that's something that will be addressed later.